# Prove: In a field of an order $2^k$, $a+a=0$ for each element $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that In a field of an order $2^k$, $a+a=0$ for each element $a$, I've been thinking about this question for too long, the only lead I have on this is the characteristic of the field, which is the minimal number of times i need to add 1 to itself in order to get zero. but how do I relate this to $2^k$? I really need some help, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know [Lagrange's theorem on finite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)?

Comment: Use Micah's hint on the additive group and remember that fields have no zero divisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show that in a field of order $2^k$, $2=0$.

Look at $F$ as an additive group. Then adding an element to itself $|F|$ times yields the unit ($0$), i.e. $2^k=|F|1=0$. This means that $\underbrace{2\cdots 2}_{k\text{ times}}=0$, so $2=0$ (because a product in a field is $0$ iff one of the factors is $0$).

Comment: just to be sure, you added 1 to itself here |F| times?

Comment: Yes. By Lagrange's theorem, if we have a group $G$ with operation $\star$ and $x$ is any element of $G$, then $\underbrace{x\star\cdots\star x}_{|G|\text{ terms}}$ is the unit of the group. Apply this with $G=F$, $\star=+$ and $x=1$..